# Pause individual torrent don't stop download

Tags: python-2.7, libtorrent

1-Call startDownloadFromMagnet(). Torrent start downloading at full speed.

2-When download is in full speed, call pauseTorrentFromIndex(). Print pause=True.

3-Call getTorrentFullInfo(), each 5 seg for 2-5 min. Torrent is in pause mode and downloading at full speed. I know that is in full speed because status().download_rate return hight values and Windows network monitor (win8.1) show me the same speeds.

As additional information, the general pause of entire session(Not show in code) works well but pause all torrents of session. I need to pause individual torrents.

```
def startDowloadFromMagnet(self, magnet, outPath):
    """ Given a magnet link, start downloading file. Return true if start do not fail """

    try:
        self.activeTorrentList.append(lt.add_magnet_uri(self.ses, magnet, {'save_path': outPath}))    
        return True
    except:
        print '\n ERROR --> Wrong Magnet link: ' + str(magnet)
        return False



def pauseTorrentFromIndex(self, index):
    """ given a torrent index pause torrent """

    print 'isPaused(before): ' + str(self.isPaused(index)) #False
    self.activeTorrentList[index].pause(0)
    print 'isPaused(after): ' + str(self.isPaused(index)) #True 
    print 'Paused torrent which index: ' + str(index) #0        
    print 'Total num torrents: ' + str(self.getNumTorrents()) #1

def getTorrentFullInfo(self, index):
    """ Given a torrent index, return full torrent info"""
    #Download speed, status, size, ...

def isPaused(self, index):
    """ Return true if torrent is paused"""
    return self.activeTorrentList[index].status().paused
```

Comment: you could see if you have any peers still, and if any of them still have transfer rates. Do you have the DHT enabled? it will also use bandwidth.

Comment: After the pause continued download with the same peers and the same upload and download speeds. Later will investigate the problem more deeply for now I pause individual torrents with "set_download_limit (1)" and "set_upload_limit(1)".

Comment: could you provide a minimal example that reproduces the problem?